# Dropping some levels of dummy-coded categorical variable in a linear regression due to too few observations

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-encoding

I want to run a linear regression in SPSS

N = 1400

Outcome variable = rating from 0 to 800 (participants saw or heard a Mandarin speaker and had to rate how pleasant the speaker was feeling)

Predictors =

1. "Status of Mandarin", i.e. 3-level nominal variable (whether the participants are native speakers /  learners / non-speakers of Mandarin)
2. "Condition", i.e. 4-level nominal variable (whether the participants saw a video recording / heard and audio recording / saw & heard a video recording with sound / only heard an unclear [i.e. low-pass filtered] audio recording)
3. Culture, i.e. 10-level nominal variable (1O cultural clusters, some participants not being categorised in any of these clusters)

I dummy-coded all variables to include them in a linear model

[image: Frequencies Culture]

As you see from this table, some levels of the "Culture" variable have too few observations, so basically I think that can only include the Confucian, the Anglo, and the Latin Europe groups. How do I deal with that with dummy coding? Should I include all 9 dummy-coded Culture variables in the model (excluding Confucian as I want that group as baseline) and only interpret the significance value and coefficients for the Anglo dummy variable and for the Latin Europe dummy variable?

I am also planning to look at interactions between Status of Mandarin and Condition (and ideally also between Status of Mandarin and Culture + between Condition and Culture, but I am not sure whether I can).

I am using SPSS at the moment but might switch to R.

In response to a comment by @rolando2, I am adding a picture of the instrument showing the gliding scales used to collect the ratings. I indeed will not consider a difference of, say 20, as meaningful.
[image: Instrument]

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "too few"?  Too few for what purpose or according to what criterion?

Comment: Actually you caught me here: I thought that it was a generally assumed rule of thumb that each dummy variable should have minimum 15% of the sample, but a quick search on the internet shows me that this rule is not assumed by everyone (and confuses me even more).

Comment: The problem stays the same though, as some participants are not categorised in any of these categories (should I have an additional dummy variable "Other" with the rest of the sample?)

Comment: A 15% rule would have no basis in any legitimate theory.  Possibly in certain applications with certain standard objectives and standard sample sizes such a rule could be helpful, but otherwise it ought to be ignored.

Comment: So I could simply include all dummy variables in the analysis (and do I need to include an "other" dummy variable to include the part of the sample that has not been categorised in any of these culture groups?)

Comment: Tangential psychometric point:  It seems you have offered 801 choices for the "feeling" rating.  If so, this is inviting "slack", arbitrariness, unreliability, which will somewhat obscure (though not bias) your results.  Few raters could meaningfully, reliably distinguish between a rating of, say, 630 and 650, let alone between 630 and 631.  One does not obtain greater and greater precision with more and more choices.

Comment: You have got a point. The range of the scale from 0 to 800 was chosen for practical matters (depending on average screen size etc), but participants would not have to pick a number. They would just glide a pointer in a two-dimensional space. See my edit in my question. Thanks!

Comment: You are going to do a 3-factor ANOVA. Unbalanced groups bring in complexity [because](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/99221/3277) factor interactions are then often correlated with main effects and even main effects correlate. Another issue is representativeness. _If_ a group of too few respondents happened to include mostly unrepresentative respondents then your estimates may be strongly biased.

Comment: One way is to exclude groups with scarce of respondents from the data, another way is to combine them in "Other" group. Yet another way is to weight the dataset so that the groups are more balanced or more close to population structure (if your study is observational, not experimental).